# Design a route planning system for transportation company

Tags: java, architecture, system

My friend was asked this interview question (Design a route planning system for transportation company), I was wondering how someone could answer this? If someone can give me pointers on the high-level components, that would be very helpful.

Comment: I have often wondered if graph theory is applicable to route planning.

Comment: yes it is applicable, Dijkstra's algorithm that I can think of. But how does everything fits in, thats my question.

Comment: I am not sure there is enough context as it depends on what the interviewers might be looking for.  Perhaps they want something along the lines of you need to break down the "map" into the components of the graph, then you need to convert the selection of start and destination into nodes on the graph and then run Dijkstras algorithm against the graph.  I think you have three or four components there.